# Почему графический редактор XML кода в Android Studio не прорисовывает изменения?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Добавил Toolbar на экран, по умолчанию на нем должно быть название и еще 2 элемента которых добавил я, но редакторе ничего не отображается. Я слышал что необходимо подключать определенные инструменты что бы рендеринг проходил корректно. На скрине видно что редактор показывает что Toolbar пуст, но если запустить приложение на нем будет надпись LearnWords, кнопка и меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить студию отображать элементы Toolbara которые я добавляю?

XML код

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.sh_am.learnwords.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Визуальный редактор студии, это не эмулятор реального устройства и он не выполняет клиентский код, чтобы заполнить виджеты контентом, а только преобразует текстовый xml-вид разметки в визуальное отображение. Таким образом в визуальном редакторе вы увидите только то, что указали через xml-атрибуты. В вашей разметке никакого заголовка тулбару через xml-атрибут не назначено, поэтому вы его не видите.

Для решения данной проблемы есть не очень правильный способ, который состоит в том, чтобы назначать виджетам некие "дефолтные" атрибуты в разметке, чтобы их было видно в визуальном редакторе, при выполнении кода они будут заменены действительными значениями.
Способ не очень хорош тем, что во первых выполняет бесполезную работу, так как "дефолтные" значения не нужны нигде, кроме как в визуальном редакторе (то есть на этапе отладки), а ресурсы устройства на их обработку расходуются постоянно. Во вторых, возможны артефакты при смене контента в виджетах, когда сначала видно "дефолтное" значение, а потом оно заменяется на реальное.

Решить эти проблемы можно вычисткой "дефолтных" атрибутов перед релизом, когда уже все работает и настроено, как надо, но это довольно муторное и неблагодарное занятие.

Для правильного решение проблемы редактор xml-разметки поддерживает [пространство имен *xmlns:tools*](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/studio/tools.php). Атрибуты, указанные в этом пространстве имен будут отображаться и действовать только непосредственно в редакторе разметки, при сборке программы они не будут включены в компиляцию и никаким образом не будут проявлять себя, естественно.

С помощью этого пространства имен мы можем назначить текущий контекст (фактически локальную тему, если она в какой то активити отличается от темы приложения), "заполнить" виджеты `ListView` и подобные айтемами, заполнить выпадающие меню и тому подобное. Для всех возможностей смотрите [официальную документацию](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes).
Так же, это пространство имен понимает практически все атрибуты виджетов из пространства имен *xmlns:android*, с той разницей, что действие этих атрибутов будет только в редакторе визуальной разметки, но не в самом приложении.

К сожалению, c атрибутами пространства имен внешних библиотек (к которым относится и виджет `Toolbar`) данный инструмент не работает и поскольку атрибут виджета `Toolbar` `title` относится именно к таким (пространство имен, вроде *xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"* - `app:title =""`), то в данном случае этот чудесный способ не поможет и придется задавать "дефолтное" значение напрямую, что не уменьшает удобства использования пространства *tools*, везде, где это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы устанавливаете заголовок вашему ToolBar'у в коде, то изменения в XML редакторе не будут показаны.

Если хотите видеть результаты в xml-редакторе, то вам стоит прописать нужные теги нужному элементу, к примеру, для ToolBar'a:

```
android:title="Название"
```

Comment: Не работает, это я изначально пытался делать, не удается